# Is caching by URL's a good practice?

Tags: php, url, caching, content-management-system

I'm bulding a fairly large and complex CMS in PHP, and my plan is to implement caching on some parts of it (with the possibility of toggeling the cache on/off for specific pages/sections). After some research I came to the conclusion that using the URL would be the best practice for locating and retreiving the cahced file. My intention is to implement a "whole page" solution to avoid obtrusive querycaching and cache the entire page, for all pages that should be cached.

The pseudocode would go like this (date-modified excluded):

```
$filename = md5($the_full_url);

if (file_exists($filename)) get_cached_file($filename);

else write_cached_file($filename);
```

Could this approach be considered good practice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it depends on if there is user generated content on the page, for example if I view the page and you view the page do we get different pages or both the same page? Is there any form of "dynamic" content on the page.

Full page caches are the most economical IF the page isn't going to change on a user/user basis. If they are likley to change on a user by user basis you can cache by [url.sessionid] if not then caching by the full url is fine.

Another alternative it to cache parts of the page which are likley to remain constant (For example blog entries)

Finally there is data caching where you just cache the dynamic data from the database locally.

The whole system depends upon your requirements.

Comment: The idea was to have stuff like product pages or forum views cached every X minutes using the "whole page" idea, and then disable caching for stuff like "user inbox" or "your forum subscriptions" (or perhaps enable querycaching/store cache by url+sessid).